# Count percentage of upper case words

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to determine the percentage of upper case words in texts

```
Sent

Include DETAILS about YOUR goal
Describe expected and actual results
Include any ERROR messages
```

The below code should be able to determine the percentage of upper case (I think), but not for words but character (and in a string):

```
alph = list(filter(str.isalpha, s))  
sum(map(str.isupper, alph)) / len(alph)
```

For looking at the upper case words in each row, I tried as follows:

```
df['UP'] = df['Sent'].str.findall(r'\b([A-Z]{2,})')
```

and this should work. However I do not know how to calculate the percentage. I hope you can give me some tips on how to calculate it. I think I would count the number of words in each row but I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try

```
df['UP'] = df['Sent'].str.findall(r'[A-Z]').str.len()
```

Or we do `count`

```
df['Sent'].str.count(r'[A-Z]')
```